# permission denied when importing recapcha

Tags: python, django, import, recaptcha

I'm using recapcha on a Django site. It shows up on forms properly, the problem comes in when I try to check if it was entered correctly:

```
from recaptcha.client import captcha
```

Gives me the error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/WebError-0.10.3-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/top_level.txt'
```

Google's not helping me on this one. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: you can check permissions with ls `-lah /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`, probably pip set ug to root:staff with no exec priveledges for latter. chmod 755 should help then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the write/read permissions on that file, or set full permissions for dist-packages to avoid similar future problem.

Comment: That was actually quite obvious. Have some points :). My main point was actually that the permissions shouldn't have been wrong in the first place... meh